# in what format does raw_fetchRow() return a simple query?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have this simple query : `$query = 'SELECT column1,column2,column3 FROM tableSelected WHERE ...'` and I used that query here in `$fetchedResults = $object->raw_fetchRow($query);` how do I access those values in $fetchedResults? is it `$fetchedResults[0]->column1`, `$fetchedResults->column1` or `$fetchedResults['column1']` ? which is which? just wanna know I'm not good with this yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fetch row basically used to fetch single row and you can access the field value like

```
echo $fetchedResults['column1'];
```

Comment: well I tested it but nope, unless I add this 'as ColVal' to `$result = $resource->raw_fetchRow("SELECT `column1` as ColVal FROM ...");` then I can access the value like this $result['ColVal'];

Comment: try to do the print_r of return result and check the array and access it accordingly.